# Tic-Tac-Toe game glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tic-tac-toe

Can someone... anyone, help me figure out why when the 'fourCorners' function is activated, it fills in 2 boxes instead of one. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a link to my code: https://codepen.io/DRick504/pen/bRGgRJ

```
  function fourCorners() {

    var compArr = [3,0,2,1]

    var compNextMove = compArr[num]

     $('#players').text(num)

    if (num===4) {

      return false;

    } else if (compNextMove===0 && $('#one').is(':empty')) {

      $('#one').text(opp)
      $('#one').slideDown(800)

    } else if (compNextMove===1 && $('#three').is(':empty')) {

      $('#three').text(opp)
      $('#three').slideDown(800)

    } else if (compNextMove===2 && $('#seven').is(':empty')) {

      $('#seven').text(opp)
      $('#seven').slideDown(800)

    } else if (compNextMove===3 && $('#nine').is(':empty')) {

      $('#nine').text(opp)
      $('#nine').slideDown(800)

    }

  num=num+1

}
```

Comment: You can use the shortcut Ctrl + K or Command + K depending on your Operating system to ensure the entire code is within the code editor

Comment: @pal4life ok thanks! can you give me any help with figuring out why my code isn't working?

Comment: I provided this comment when reviewing the questions. Now the codepen is not active any more.